# TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property - Karma

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, karma-jasmine

While running test cases(spec.js) through command grunt karma:unit, I'm getting below error-

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'assign' of object '[object Location]'

The pseudo Code which throws the error is:

```
$window.window.location.assign = _.noop;

spyOn($window.window.location, 'assign');
```

I tried putting below line above everything to fix it, but in vain-

```
$window.window.location.assign.writable = true;
```

Could someone share his/her views to fix it? Thanks !!

Comment: What does `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.location,"assign")` show?

Answer (score 2):

`window.location.assign` is not writable:

```
> Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.location, 'assign')

{value: ƒ, writable: false, enumerable: true, configurable: false}
```

This means that there is no way that you can temporarily overwrite it to spy on it.

There are two possibilities I can think of:

1. Wrap all calls to `$window.location.assign` in a custom call to an angular service that you create and can therefore spy on. (**EDIT**: use the angularjs `$window` service to facilitate mockability and testing.
2. Test that after you call Location.assign, the page now has the expected URL.

2 will be more difficult since this may cause you to navigate away from the test. I'd recommend 1. It's generally an easy refactor and makes your testing significantly easier.

Comment: While window is globally available in JavaScript, it causes testability problems, because it is a global variable. In AngularJS we always refer to it through the [$window service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window), so it may be overridden, removed or mocked for testing.

Comment: Thank you..that's helpful !!